Potential inconsistence of historical ETH balance provided by Etherscan
I am tryingto infer the historical ETH balance of 0x3cc3ae64f26c8fa893358e5ae7717a0d001c0940 using the transactions provided by Etherscan, but I have encountered an inconsistence. For example, the address didn't receive any ETH on 2023-03-02 as showned by etherscan, but the balancecheck-tool indicates that the address had an increase of 0.756691545337605533 ETH on 2023-03-02 compared to 2023-03-01, which is inconsistent.
Additionally, even balancecheck-tool shows different ETH balance in one day. For example, this figure shows that the ETH balance on 2023-07-05 is both 500.05136 and 32.6382, which can be confusing.
Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I can only answer your first question.
The transaction history you see on etherscan corresponds only to transactions where the account was the origin or the main target of the transactions. It's possible that the account was targeted inter-transaction, in this case it's listed on the "Internal Transactions" page. Unfortunately it's hard to find these transfers since ETH doesn't emit logs.

Really thanks for your answers!! May I ask whether internal transactions involve erc20 tokens? Because I only saw ETH on the internal transactions page. Thank you a lot!!

To track erc20 tokens you can just look at the token transfers page.
